# Is the Solace message broker compatible with "regular" AMQP or JMS clients?

Tags: jms, amqp, solace

I'd like to use regular AMQP or JMS clients to connect to a Solace message broker but don't know enough about these protocols to know if they are compatible. From what I can tell Solace implements AMQP and JMS bu possibly with incompatible extensions (e.g. "message vpn").

Does Solace have incompatible extensions, particularly for JMS, or is there a straightforward way to get a JMS client to speak to a Solace broker with "message vpn" enabled?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "regular AMQP or JMS clients"? JMS is an **API** so every JMS-compatible message broker will have their own JMS client implementation.

Comment: Okay I think I understand:  I need to use a Solace client to connect to a Solace broker, it doesn't implement some "standard" protocol that is compatible with other clients, in contrast to something like AMQP.

Comment: To be more accurate, if you want to use JMS then you need to use the Solace JMS client implementation to connect to a Solace broker. If you're using a standard protocol like AMQP or MQTT then you can use any client on any platform in any language which speaks those protocols.

Answer (score 4):

The choice is yours as Solace provides both a [JMS client implementation](https://docs.solace.com/API/Solace-JMS-API/Solace-JMS-Overview.htm) and it also [supports AMQP 1.0](https://docs.solace.com/API/AMQP/Using-AMQP.htm).

Keep in mind that JMS is an **API** and AMQP is a **protocol**. The JMS API can be implemented over *any* suitable wire protocol, and AMQP can be exposed via any suitable API. JMS is Java-based and there are many JMS implementations using different protocols under the covers. There are also many AMQP clients written in different languages on different platforms all with different APIs. There are even projects which combine both JMS and AMQP like [Qpid JMS](https://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/index.html).

Comment: Okay thanks. Is there a place I can lookup the documentation for "message vpns" in the JMS API?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. The JMS specification makes no mention of "Message VPN" functionality. That is something specific to Solace. Also, I think all the configuration related to Message VPN on Solace is server-side and should be transparent to clients.

Comment: @poolfroof just a heads up that if you are connecting to Solace via OTS software that already supports the JMS API you usually just need to drop the Solace JMS jars in and then specify user@messagevpn as the username.

Answer (score 0):

Solace's PubSub+ event broker works on binary payloads which means that you can indeed publish and consume messages on cross protocols and APIs.
The Solace APIs have detailed documentation on how to process the payload in a type agnostic fashion.

As you can see in this diagram, we support a wide range of APIs and protocol integrations.
[image: Solace supported APIs and protocols]

There are also sample codes present over at this Github account listing examples on using Solace broker with JMS and AMQP : https://github.com/SolaceSamples?

Answer (score -2):

(Answering my own question).

I basically wanted to know if it was possible to connect to a Solace/JMS broker using more popular messaging libraries. As far as I can tell the answer is no in general.

For example,
one feature of JMS is JNDI lookup of the `InitialContextFactory`. I don't think that is possible to do outside of a JMS library.

Comment: Solace provides a JMS client and it supports AMQP 1.0. You only need to use JNDI if you're using JMS and even then it's optional in most circumstances. I don't understand why you're saying "the answer is no." Can you clarify your position?

Comment: I don't control the broker so I don't think it's optional on the client side if the broker is using it.

Comment: Even if Solace is providing JNDI service your JMS client doesn't have to use it. It can use the `SolJmsUtility` to create the necessary JMS admin objects like connection factories and destinations as described in the [Solace documentation](https://docs.solace.com/API/Solace-JMS-API/Extensions-to-Standard-JMS.htm). If you're using anything other than Java or if you're using a standard protocol like AMQP or MQTT then you don't need to use JNDI.